# What method to call inside TimSort method?

Tags: java, sorting, timsort

TimSort is an algorithm that will be used by default in Java 7 for sorting.

I found this source, but I don't understand which method to call since all of them are private.
Can anybody understand? Thank you.

http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't call anything.

It has sort methods that are package private to `java.util`. You let it call them when you call the `Arrays.sort()` function or something like it.

This is made clear by the comment:

```
/*
 * The next two methods (which are package private and static) constitute
 * the entire API of this class.  Each of these methods obeys the contract
 * of the public method with the same signature in java.util.Arrays.
 */

static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    sort(a, 0, a.length, c);
}

static <T> void sort(T[] a, int lo, int hi, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    ...
}
```

Judging by the time of my last comment, this took less than 15 minutes to do:

- http://pastebin.com/VNyUutiD - SortTest.java
- http://pastebin.com/deGAfWZj - TimSort.java

And the result:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java SortTest
Time for default: 4094ms
Time for timsort: 3813ms

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>
```

Comment: damn. Do you know any "complete" source of the Tim Sort in Java? I guess I can't call the method yet since we are not in Java 7. =x Thank you.

Comment: @Seva do you have a specific need to call TimSort? And, is there anything stopping you from copy/pasting that and making a method or two `public` and changing what package it's in?

Comment: yes, I want to test the method speed. In that code there's a line calling Arrays.Sort, which in the currently Java version would only call a tuned quick sort or a tuned merge sort. It won't call the TimSort, since it will be implemented in Java 7.

Comment: So, does anybody know a complete source please?

Comment: @Seva you could modify that to work by adding "public" before the two methods I listed, and then changing the package to whatever package you want... then you could call `TimSort.sort(myArray,myComparator);`

Comment: man, that's very interesting, I will mark you as answer, but I think the code you created isn't correct. Look inside the TimSort class to this line: Arrays.sort(a, lo, hi); This line will call the default implementation of Java 6 which is a tunned quick sort or merge sort. Don't you agree? Thanks.

Comment: @seva I don't agree. It only does this if the comparator is null. I know it is not null.